# Why does the sphere not roll?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

It says in the first case that the sphere never rolls. Is it possible for a sphere to not roll and just slide?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's just an assumption in the context of an example.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the source of the problem - this is recommended when asking - see [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#9960)  Based on Google search, it seems to be from [Krishna's Rigid Dynamics](https://books.google.com/books?id=kugNQJiyx58C&pg=PA138), although basically an identical text appears in [An Elementary Treatise On the Dynamics of a Particle and of Rigid Bodies](https://books.google.com/books?id=EHE3AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA242).

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 5 decades since I studied physics, so some of my terminology is probably wrong. But, anyway ...

There are two forces acting on the sphere: the pull of gravity, and the reactive force of the plane it's sitting on. The first of these always acts through the center of the sphere, obviously. If there is no friction, the second force acts along a line normal to the inclined plane at the point of contact, so it also passes through the center of the sphere. So both forces act along lines passing through the center of the sphere, which means there is zero torque, and the sphere will not rotate. Therefore, it will slide, rather than rolling.

Answer (score 0):

The derivation shows that for this case the contact point $A$ has a positive velocity:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{A} &= \dot{x} - a \dot{\theta} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} g  \,(\underbrace{2\sin \alpha - 7\mu \cos \alpha}_{> 0 \, \text{(first case)}}) \\
\end{align}
$$
so it moves downwards (in direction of $g$) and with it the sphere, which had zero angular velocity $\dot{\theta}(0) = 0$.